# Why does iTunes download different version of my existing songs

Tags: itunes, music

Frequently, iTunes will download an album version or an alternate version of a song that I already have. I think it does this whenever I play a song that iTunes thinks I should have *their* version. At one point, it doubled nearly every one of my 20GB of songs. It took me hours to delete everything, reinstall iTunes, and still lose all my meta data.

Now less than a week later, it's starting to happen again.

a) Why is this happening? My preferences has "Apple Music Connect" and "Show Apple Music" both as disabled.

b) Is there an alternative that doesn't require using several different programs to move music & files easily & automatically? I have many podcasts, playlists, books, and apps. I know this question belongs in another thread. But I'm frustrated enough to scream.

Comment: I'm tempted to think iTunes Match... though I've never used it or apple music personally. My iTunes does nothing I didn't tell it to do.

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks. iTunes Match may be the problem, even though I've never subscribed to the service. It seems though that the automatic download option must also be turned off on every device. Hopefully, this will work. It's amazing the lengths Apple will go through to persuade its user to switch back to PC.

On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch
Choose Settings > iTunes & App Store.
Tap your Apple ID.
Tap View Apple ID. If prompted, enter your password.
Scroll to the iTunes in the Cloud section.
Turn off iTunes Match Renewal.